# Equivlence between integrable function and $J$-measurable set.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

> Let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ bounded and positive in the block $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$. Then $f$ is integrable if only if the set $C(f) = \{\,(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{m+1} \mid x \in A,\; 0 \leq y \leq f(x)\,\}$ be $J$-measurable. In affirmative case,
>   $$\int_{A}f(x)\mathrm{d}x = \operatorname{vol}C(f).$$

I don't know how to connect the integrability of $f$ with measure of $C(f)$. I know that $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is $J$-measurable if only if $\partial X$ has null measure. So, the question is reduced to

> - $f$ is integrable if only if $\partial C(f)$ is a null set in $\mathbb{R}^{m+1}$.

More over, $f$ is integrable if only if $D_{f}$ (discontinuity points of $f$) is a null set. So, we can work with

> - $D_{f}$ is null set if only if $\partial C(f)$ is a null set in $\mathbb{R}^{m+1}$.

The last version seems to me a little more connected, but still, I don't know how to prove it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is integrable if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a partition $P$ of $A$ such that $U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon.$ Notice that the upper/lower sum difference

$$U(P,f) - L(P,f) = \sum_{j=1}^n (M_j - m_j) \,vol(R_j)$$

is the sum of volumes of a finite collection of rectangles $R_j \times [m_j,M_j]$ that covers the graph $\{(x,f(x)): x \in A\}$ which must, therefore, have measure $0$. The other parts of the boundary of $C(f)$ are sections of $m-$dimensional hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^{m+1}$ and obviously have measure $0$.

Comment: I don't understand "The other parts of the boundary of $C(f)$ are sections of $m-$dimensional hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^{m+1}$ and obviously have measure $0$". A previous questions says that: *Given a partition $P$ of $A$, there is a partition $Q$ $(m+1)$-dimensional of $A \times [m,M]$ such that $U(P,f) - L(P,f)$ is the sum of volumes of all blocks of $Q$ containing the graph of $f$*. Is this what you are using? It seems to me that you are proving that $\partial C(f)$ is a null set, but I cannot see it. I would like you to explain more, if you can.

Comment: The boundary of $C(f)$ has a "top section" which is the graph of $f$ and by this or the previous answer that can be covered with blocks where the sum of volumes is less than $\epsilon$.  The "bottom section" is $\{(x,y): x \in A, \, y=0$ which is in a lower dimensional plane so again of measure $0$.  Same applies to the other sides of $C(f)$.  Imagine if $m=1$ and $A = [a,b]$, the bottom is the segment from $a$ to $b$ on the $x-axis$ so it has measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  And so on ...

Comment: I'm sure you know how to show that a line segment in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has measure $0$, or a section of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Similarly a section of an $m-$dimensional plane in $\mathbb{R}^{m+1}$ has measure $0$.

Comment: Nice. I see about the "top section" and "bottom section", but I cannot see how this implies the boundary has measure $0$.

Comment: Again, start with $m = 1$.  The boundary of $C(f)$ is $\{(x,f(x)):x \in [a,b]\}\cup \{(x,y): x= a, \, 0 \leqslant y \leqslant f(a)\} \cup \{(x,y): x = b, \, 0 \leqslant y \leqslant f(b)\} \cup \{(x,y): a \leqslant x \leqslant b, \, y=0\}$ The boundary is the union of three line segments and the "top" which is the graph of $f$.  Each of the four pieces has measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: If $m = 2$, and $A = [a,b] \times [c,d]$ then one of the "sides" of the boundary is $\{(x,y,z): x = a, c \leqslant y \leqslant d, \, 0 \leqslant z \leqslant f(a,y)\}$ which has measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, etc.

Comment: One last attempt -- a side of $C(f)$ is a bounded rectifiable subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$, so has finite area and can be covered by a finite set of rectangles where the sum of volumes is less than $\epsilon$.  Just make the height of the rectangles in the perpendicular direction less than $\epsilon/$ (area of side).

Comment: Great! Thank you!